# Does Entropy values enough creterion to determine the nature of any probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, entropy

Entropy is the measure of randomness of a process or variable and it can be defined as follows. for a random variable $X \in$ set $A$ :- $H(X)= \sum_{x_i \in A} -p(x_i) \log (p(x_i)) $, Now there are many properties of any Probability distribution whch it give us some informations about the nature of that distribution( Uniform , not uniforme , Gamma distribution,...) like :Skewnews , Kurtosis , Mean, Variance , Entropy, My question here probably trivial , I want to know,  Does Entropy Values Enough to determine the nature of any defined probability distribution continious or discret ? And if so how that ? For examle if Entropy is null what this inform us about distribution nature ? , if it is 1 What this give us ?.. ect

Comment: Note sure what you mean by the "nature"  of the distribution, but it is possible for two different distributions to have the same entropy.

Comment: Thanks, For examle if we have an arbitary distribution its Entropy is 0 What this means ? Can we know something about that distribution ?

Comment: Not a heck of a lot: a single number cannot identify any distribution uniquely.  Indeed, nor can any finite number of properties of the distribution (except in "edge" cases).